# What's wrong with google MAP Api?

Tags: c#, geolocation, location

Here is the Uri i refer to:

```
string.Format("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/{1}?address={0}&sensor=false", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(address), OutputType)
```

This is response i get in server:

```
    <GeocodeResponse>
           <status>OVER_QUERY_LIMIT</status>.
           <error_message>You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.</error_message>
</GeocodeResponse>
```

**`EDIT: Please notice i have done only 1 request.`**

What I'm doing wrong? All I need it's ***`Longitude/Latitude`***

Comment: They recently reduced the number of free calls to 2500 a day. Are you simply over the limit?

Answer (score 2):

Google limits you usage of their geocoding api to 2500 request per day per IP address

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#Limits

Google is telling you in the response that you have exceeded that limit.  Someone else must be using the api on your network.

Comment: It's totally on server and I havent seen any thing how can I fix it?
And btw it doesn't helps me m8.

Comment: Have you tried it using a different network/IP Address? I just tried this with success: `http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=1600 pennsylvania avenue washington dc&sensor=false'

Comment: Yes I have and it's actually works, but how do I fix it on my web server?

Comment: Might your web server be in a shared hosting environment?  If so, you are sharing those 2500 geocoding request limit with others and the only solution you have available is to use a private host VM with it's own IP address.

Comment: Also I will add that you can also purchase the Maps API for business which will track your requests using a ClientId rather than the IP address (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/webservices/#cryptographic_signing_key)

Comment: Hmm, that's is interesting, thanks I will get back to you with that,

Comment: Of course you can use a proxy service like [QuotaGuard](http://www.quotaguard.com/). This can be another option. Please mark as answered if this resolves your issue

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of 10 requests per second too. You can check all the limits here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/faq?hl=pt-br#usage_limits